# Get JS file via HTTPS from a HTTP page

Tags: javascript, http, https, resources, security

Okay, so what are the ramifications of getting a JS file via an HTTPS call while on a HTTP page.
I assume it would just be a little bit of extra overhead. Would there be any warnings about this call from any certain browser?

Don't ask why. It's just hypothetical.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be any warnings in any browser. You can try it out this URL - http://www.530geeks.com/mixed-content.html. I tested with ie6 and firefox 3.5, they don't complain.

Its logical too - the host page is being served over http, there is no implied trust with the connection. So there is nothing to warn the user.

Answer (score 1):

This will probably trigger the "Mix of secure and insecure" content alert in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes IE (and maybe other browsers) get nervous and complain about pages having a mix of secure and insecure content.  Whether what you're doing would cause that would require a simple test.

Comment: I think this only happens in the reverse situation, where you have an HTTPS page with HTTP resources. Sripathi's answer provides an example that matches the OP's situation. Can you provide any browsers that issue a warning when viewing it?

Comment: I think you're right, @IanDunn - the cases I know of for sure involve a "container" page that's HTTPS, and something like an `<iframe>` that's got an HTTP "src" value.  I don't think I'd give this answer today (two years later :-)  but the point about just trying it out with a simple mock-up is still valid.